# how to calculate manually with the formula according to the code below

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, tfidfvectorizer

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"Final Tweet": ["bad delivery", "bad product"]})

tf_idf = TfidfVectorizer(binary=True)

tfidf_mat = tf_idf.fit_transform(df["Final Tweet"]).toarray()

tfidf = pd.DataFrame(tfidf_mat, columns=tf_idf.get_feature_names_out())

tfidf.head()

        bad  delivery   product
0  0.579739  0.814802  0.000000
1  0.579739  0.000000  0.814802

df.head()
    Final Tweet
0  bad delivery
1   bad product
```

I've done manual calculations using various formulas but I got different results from the jupyter notebook output above. can you help me to calculate manually? so that the resulting value can be the same as the above

Comment: it's my Final Tweet
bad delivery
bad product

Comment: What is it you are trying to calculate, what data are you using to drive calculations.  Without a context and an objective it is difficult or impossible to provide assistance

Answer (score 0):

Following the nomenclature from Wikipedia's [TF-IDF article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf):

### Term frequencies in each document

`tf(t, d) = f_{t,d} / (sum_{t' in d} (f_{t',d}))`

- tf("bad", "bad delivery") = 1 / (1 + 1) = 1/2 = 0.5
- tf("delivery", "bad delivery") = 1 / (1 + 1) = 1/2 = 0.5
- tf("product", "bad delivery") = 0 / (1 + 1) = 0/2 = 0.0
- tf("bad", "bad product") = 1 / (1 + 1) = 1/2 = 0.5
- tf("delivery", "bad product") = 0 / (1 + 1) = 0/2 = 0.0
- tf("product", "bad product") = 1 / (1 + 1) = 1/2 = 0.5

**Note**: the more frequently a word is in a document, the larger its TF becomes

### Inverse document frequencies

`idf(t) = log [ (1 + n) / (1 + df(t)) ] + 1`

- idf("bad") = ln((2+1)/(2+1))+1 = ln(3/3) + 1 = 1.0
- idf("delivery") = ln((2+1)/(1+1))+1 = ln(3/2) + 1 = 1.405465
- idf("product") = ln((2+1)/(1+1))+1 = ln(3/2) + 1 = 1.405465

**Note**: the rarer a word is in the corpus, the larger its IDF becomes

### TF*IDF (not normalized)

`tfidf(t, d) = tf(t, d) * idf(t)`

- tfidf("bad", "bad delivery") = 0.5 * 1.0 = 0.5
- tfidf("delivery", "bad delivery") = 0.5 * 1.405465 = 0.702733
- tfidf("product", "bad delivery") = 0.0 * 1.405465 = 0.0
- tfidf("bad", "bad product") = 0.5 * 1.0 = 0.5
- tfidf("delivery", "bad product") = 0.0 * 1.405465 = 0.0
- tfidf("product", "bad product") = 0.5 * 1.405465 = 0.702733

**Note**: the product balances the overall rarity of the terms in the corpus with their frequency on each specific document)

### TF*IDF (normalized so each document's L2-norm equals 1.0)

Divide each document vector "coordinates" by the [L2-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) of the vector, to obtain a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector):

- tfidf("bad", "bad delivery") = 0.5 / √(0.5² + 0.702733² + 0.0²) = 0.579739
- tfidf("delivery", "bad delivery") = 0.702733 / √(0.5² + 0.702733² + 0.0²) = 0.814802
- tfidf("product", "bad delivery") = 0.0 / √(0.5² + 0.702733² + 0.0²) = 0.0
- tfidf("bad", "bad product") = 0.5 / √(0.5² + 0.0² + 0.702733²) = 0.579739
- tfidf("delivery", "bad product") = 0.0 / √(0.5² + 0.0² + 0.702733²) = 0.0
- tfidf("product", "bad product") = 0.702733 / √(0.5² + 0.0² + 0.702733²) = 0.814802

You can also review the [relevant code in scikit-learn source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/98cf537f5/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py#L1661-L1719).